# (Oracle) LIKE Clause not Working with Numeric Bind Variables

Tags: node.js, oracle

I'm having problems getting Oracle's LIKE clause working with numeric bind variables.

In the examples below the TABLEID column is numeric.

In SQLDeveloper I can write `SELECT * FROM TABLEX WHERE TABLEID LIKE ('201%');` which works fine. However, when I try the same query in code using a bind variable: `SELECT * FROM TABLEX WHERE TABLEID LIKE :bindVar`

I get an ORA-01722: invalid number error.

I've tried surrounding the bind var with () and have tried adding the % symbol to the end of the bind value with no luck.

I'm using NodeJS to make the database calls.
Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are defining, populating and binding the value for the call. It looks like what you are doing should still work, via implicit conversion, just as it does with a fixed value. Are you sure you actually want to use like? That will match 201, 2010, 20100, 2019999999 etc. Which might be fine, we don't; know what the data represents; but looking for a range of numbers *might* be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Datatypes should match.

If `TABLEID` column's datatype is `NUMBER` and you're *comparing* it to a string ( (in `like '201%'`, `'201%'` is a string), then you'd apply `TO_CHAR` function to that column:

```
select * from tablex
where to_char(tableid) like :bindVar
```

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out the problem ended up being not with my code but the data within the table itself. Sorry to waste yall's time!

Comment: Please don't answer your own questions. See [answer].

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.